# neo4j Cypher Query to return relationships along a path

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm working with a Neo4j data set that looks like this:

[image: Sample data]

I'm trying to write a query that returns all paths from the green node `84` to node `88` that **also returns/includes the blue nodes that have a `Files` relationship to the gray nodes along the paths**

So far, my query looks like this:

```
MATCH (startingstatus:green {id: 84}),
(endingstatus:green {id: 88}),
path = (startingstatus) - [StatusOut*0..5] -> (endingstatus),
(scenario:gray) - [Files] -> (form:blue) 
RETURN *;
```

The problem is that right now, the query returns every `gray - [Files] -> blue` relationship in the database (e.g. the image above), **I only want the blue nodes with the relationship to the gray node with the ids `4`, `20`, and `21`** since those are the nodes along the path.

*I hope this makes sense. I apologize for having to rename some of the nodes.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its hard to test the query without a sample data set, but you can try this solution using [filter()](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/list/#functions-filter), [nodes()](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/list/#functions-nodes) and [UNWIND](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/unwind/):

```
MATCH path = (startingstatus:green {id: 84}) - [:StatusOut|:StatusIn*0..5] -> (endingstatus:green {id: 88})
WITH path, filter(node in nodes(path) where node:gray) as grayNodes
UNWIND grayNodes as grayNode
MATCH (grayNode)-[:Files]->(blueNode:blue)
RETURN path, grayNode, blueNode
```

To explain: I'm extracting the gray nodes from the path. Then I match the blue nodes related to these gray nodes.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a shot. The data here is sensitive, so I'm sorry for having to obfuscate

Comment: @Nick I have updated my answer to correct a typo. Please, try again.

Comment: that worked when I removed the colons from the relationships:
i.e. `MATCH path = (startingstatus:green {id: 84}) - [StatusOut*0..5] -> (endingstatus:green {id: 88})`
I'm pretty new to neo4j, do you know why that is the case?

Comment: @Nick Colons indicate a relationship type. If you remove the colon then you are not matching by relationship type, but only assigning the relationship to a variable called `StatusOut`. Looking at your data model more closely I realized that you have `:StatusOut` and `:StatusIn` relationship types. So I updated my answer to match considering both relationship types.

Comment: @Nick please try again.

Comment: Thanks for the info, trying now